# Using Javascript to add to REST 2013 Sharepoint list "SPFieldMultiChoice" type

Tags: rest

I'm trying to add to a checkbox field in my company's 2013 Sharepoint install. I'm using javascript as I've built a Chrome Extension to do some work hitting several sites and compiling information, then putting it in Sharepoint.

I'm getting stuck on how to add to a field "SPFieldMultiChoice". Here's what the data looks like, and I've tried all types of things with no success:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    ... other fields ...
    'Divisional' : 'Yes'});
```

Here's the error I get: `An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected`

I understand this to mean that I need to make it in object, like this:

```
    'Divisional' : {'Yes'}
```

But that doesn't work either because obviously it needs a key name to go with the value... but what?

I've also tried:

```
    'Divisional' : ['Yes']
```

Earlier, I had the URL problem described here: [REST POST: How to add a list item with 'people and group', 'choice,' and 'URL' fields?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71827/rest-post-how-to-add-a-list-item-with-people-and-group-choice-and-url-f) but that is fixed for me. I tried to do the same type of thing, by making it an array or object or array of objects, but I don't know what properties (like, in the case of the URL: Description & Url) to set.

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo! After more searching and some trial and error, I figured it out:

```
'Divisional' : {'results' : ['Yes']}
```

I'm guessing since the value is a javascript array, it can take several options, maybe like this:

```
'Divisional' : {'results' : ['Yes','Of Course','Like, totally','Yup']}
```

Hope that helps cut a few hours of your next interaction with SP and leave a few hairs, if you still have any.